# How to create pdf from dwg?

Tags: java

How to convert dwg file to pdf file using java code on command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling the [AutoCAD DWG and DXF To PDF Converter](http://www.verypdf.com/autocad-dwg-dxf-to-pdf/help.htm) from the command line.